# Placing 2 divs (top bottom) behind container div

Tags: html, css, css-float

Im trying to place background divs behind the container. I thought i would place one div at the top and one at the bottom. Then make the container have a position:relative. But only the top goes behind the container. This is what it looks like

http://oi62.tinypic.com/2lm3mvk.jpg

And this is how i want it to look like

http://oi57.tinypic.com/5zjjvs.jpg

Both blue divs are suppossed to be behind and the brown div is the container. The red divs are header/footer. How am I suppossed to do this?

```
 <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="top"></div>
            <div class="blueLeft"></div>
            <div class="padding"></div>
            <div id="container"></div>
            <div class="blueRight"></div>
            <div id="bottom"></div>


        </div>
    </body>

#wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#top,#bottom{
    background-color: red;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    clear:both;
}

#container{
    background-color: brown;
    width:800px;
    height:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.blueLeft{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    float:left;
}

.blueRight{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Both of the linked images are the same.

Comment: I added your images in your question but they look the same to me.

Comment: Have you tried `z-index`? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: The images look the same, btw...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this is what you wanted.

http://jsfiddle.net/vleong2332/pq3823tz/

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div class="blueTop"></div>
    <div class="padding"></div>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div class="blueBottom"></div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
}
#top,#bottom{
    background-color: red;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    clear:both;
}
#container{
    background-color: brown;
    width:800px;
    height:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
.blueTop{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
}
.blueBottom{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 200px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

On HTML, I changed the class to blueTop and blueBottom since they would be more accurate semantically.

On CSS, since I don't think you'd need the float, I removed them. I used position: absolute on the blue divs. The top one doesn't need to be re-adjusted because the flow already puts it where you want it. For the bottom, I need to position the bottom on top of the red since it goes against the normal flow. z-index is to put the blueBottom behind the brown div.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem! I tried positioning them absolute but it wouldn't work. I think i forgot to make #wrapper relative when I tried. I never seem to understand how absolute and relative works..

Comment: I had troubles too, but this article helped clear it out for me. https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Answer (score 0):

Using your example, you could just give `#container` a negative margin equal to the height of the second blue `div`.

So for example:

```css
#wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#top,#bottom{
    background-color: red;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    clear:both;
}

#container{
    background-color: brown;
    width:800px;
    height:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: -300px;
}

.blueLeft{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    float:left;
}

.blueRight{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="top"></div>
  <div class="blueLeft"></div>
  <div class="padding"></div>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <div class="blueRight"></div>
  <div id="bottom"></div>

</div>
  </body>
```

However, you may want to consider doing this differently.

Comment: Why? Should I avoid using negative margins?

Comment: @Terv No, negative margins are fine, nudging content up is totally acceptable. I was just thinking that it might be better to position them absolutely, but it all depends on what exactly you end up doing with them.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having isn't that your `#container` element is "on top" of your bottom blue float in a Z-axis way, it's that it's above it vertically in the document (basically, the float is clearing your `#container`.

Try adding `margin-top: -300px;` to your `.blueRight` CSS and see if that gives you what you are looking for.